# Do you include a reference category for a series of dummy variables in a probit regression?

Tags: probability, categorical-data, interpretation, references, probit

Do you include a reference category for a series of dummy variables in a probit regression? If so, how would you interpret the reference category?

The question underlying my confusion is that I don't understand what purpose the constant term serves in a probit regression. I think the constant is simply the Y assumed as 1. Given that Y is assumed as 1 serving as the constant, what are the marginal effects of the other variables on whether this will occur?

If there is a reference category then it seems that the constant is equal to Y assumed as 1 times the probability of the reference category occurring when Y is equal to 1.

Please explain this to me and cite your sources so I can read more about it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a probit model with one binary predictor, you can interpret $F(\hat\alpha)$ as the probability of success (or whatever $Y=1$ means) for the baseline group. $F()$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal.

If you also have continuous covariates, then it's the probability of success with them at zero (which is not really useful most of the time unless you centered the continuous variables by subtracting the mean, which gives you the probability for a baseline observation with the average characteristics). If you have two or more sets of dummies, it's the probability of success for the baseline observation for each set (female and single, for example). Each baseline effect is not identified separately.

Dummies in non-linear models are explained very well in [this Stata Journal paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0086) by Tamás Bartus.